# How do I get a Brother DCP-315CN printer working?

Tags: printing, brother

I need detailed instructions for an absolute beginner to install my brother dcp-315cn under
ubuntu 11.10. I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 32bit, then click this link. [Brother Printer Driver Download](http://www.brother.com/cgi-bin/agreement/agreement.cgi?dlfile=http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/cupswrapperMFC210C-1.0.2-3.i386.deb&lang=English_gpl) from their website. It recommends you to use the MFC-210C driver on the Brother support site, which I've given you the link to there. All you should have to do is click "Accept" for the license terms and then it will ask you to download it or open it in "Ubuntu Software Center". Open it in the Ubuntu Software Center and click install.

You might need to restart your computer afterwards but that should just work.